# Unable to download torrents when using a VPN

Tags: vpn

I am running Ubuntu 13.04 and using OpenVPN and vpnbook. When I am using a VPN I am unable to download torrents. I have tried it on 3 different torrent clients (qBittorrent, Deluge, and Transmission). Deluge just says "Checking" and never begins downloading. qBittorrent says "stalled" next to the torrent and Transmission does not say anything and just doesn't download. Is there some network setting I am missing or some OpenVPN config I need to do?

Comment: Did you try to set `Proxy` and `Random Port greater than 16000`?

Comment: An initial troubleshooting step: are you sure this VPN connection allows torrents? Have you downloaded torrents through this VPN before?

Comment: @Alaa +1, the VPN might not even allow torrents. Also make sure the torrent is extremely healthy, experiment with DHT on and off.

Comment: I have never done it before but on their site it says they do allow torrents

Answer (score 1):

Install openvpn:

`sudo apt-get install openvpn`

Download the config files from [www.vpnbook.com](http://www.vpnbook.com)

In the terminal type :

`openvpn --config vpnbook-euro1-udp25000.ovpn`

Then set the port in the connection dialog in qbittorrent to 25000.

That's it! It should be downloading fine through VPN.

Check your IP via [www.whatismyip.com](http://www.whatismyip.com) and verify.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the port 25000, it's noted in the vpnbook page : this for pptp and openvpn

Comment: Can you explain how, and why?